# How to Access Bin Folder of Active Project using visual studio 2010 add in

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I want to access Bin folder of active project using object (_applicationObject) that i get it after create add-in project
my code till now:

```
object ob = _applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
 // i want this result
 // D:/Myproject/Bin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

returns the current working directory.

or you can use

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: i want current Directory of selected project not addIn project

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location this code get me location of plugin not location of selected project

Comment: do you want to get the bin folder of main project or the plugin project (class library)?

Comment: if you want to get the bin folder of main project use Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName; usually we put the plugin dll's in a folder under main project and the current Directory call from the dll will always return the folder path.