# Getting directory of current project, and not visual studio plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently trying to write a plugin for visual studio that accesses the bin folder of the currently open project in Visual studio. However, all the solutions I have come across simply return the bin folder and directory of the plugin that is I am writing. For example, I have used the method detailed in the article below, which claims to return the current project's directory.

[How to Access Bin Folder of Active Project using visual studio 2010 add in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376697/how-to-access-bin-folder-of-active-project-using-visual-studio-2010-add-in)

```
path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName;
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(path);
```

Is there anything I am missing on how to make this work?

Comment: Yeah that won't work at all. What do you want the bin folder for? There's a few different things you might want depending upon exactly what you ultimately need to do.

Comment: I need to access an .exe. Ultimately trying to implement a rollback extension.

Comment: Not sure I follow your scenario. "Rollback extension"?

Comment: Sorry, basically a very similar situation to this, http://thomasvm.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/launch-fluentmigrator-from-within-visual-studio/ but I want the setting up of fluent migrator to be automated as an visual studio extension.

Answer (score 0):

A Visual Studio project can have several project configurations, each one with a different output build folder that is set in the project properties window, Compile/Build section, Build output path. Furthermore, the output build folder can be absolute or relative to the project folder.

The code of this article gets the absolute output build folder for the active configuration of each project of a solution:

HOWTO: Get the output build folder from a Visual Studio add-in or macro

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2009/MZ2009015.aspx